# Selenium IDE: how to append int variable after string

Tags: selenium-ide

I have just started using selenium IDE and I am trying to append a integer value after a constant string:

```
variable x = string
variable y = integer
append string+integer
```

anyone so kind to help me out?
I have never used java in my life.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean javascript? If you're in the IDE I assume you do.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the values in another string like:

```
String name = "test";
int number = 1;
String combined = name+number;
```